# What is the object translating part of a monadic endofunctor?

Tags: functional-programming, monads

A monad is an endofunctor $T:C\rightarrow C$ with natural transformations $\eta:id_C\rightarrow T$ and $\mu:T^2\rightarrow T$.

Being natural transformations mean that $$T(f)\circ \eta_A = \eta_B\circ id_C(f)$$ should hold and $$T(f)\circ\mu_A = \mu_B\circ T^2(f)$$ also. These are the algebraic expressions that the defining diagrams of natural transformations commute.

Translating this to the language of functional programming, $\eta$ is `unit`, and a polymorphic one, so $\eta_{nat}$ is the monomorphisation of `unit` to the `nat` type. $\mu$ is `join` in the same sense. The functor $T$ consists of two things: it takes object and morphisms. The latter part is called `map` in functional programming. So the above equations translate to

```
map f o unit = unit o f
```

where, if `f` is `A -> B` then this is

```
map f o unit(A) = unit(B) o f
```

but that is usually handled with a polymorphic type system and the second equation is

```
map f o join = join o map (map f)
```

So, `map` is the morphism-translating part of the endofunctor $T$.

But what is the object-translating part of $T$ in functional programming? Is it the type operator `M` when we write `unit: 'a -> 'a M` ?

Comment: I think this question would be more suitable on [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/); I'm not sure it is on-topic here.

Comment: I had a similar question concerning monads and a moderator moved it from the Computer Science site to here: https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/why-do-they-use-bind-in-haskell-over-kleisli-composition

Comment: That other question is on-topic here because it is about the reasoning behind a design decision made by the Haskell developers. Could you elaborate on how this question relates to programming language design or implementation?

Comment: I let the moderators decide. In an ideal world, a functional programming Stack Exchange site would be the place for my question.

Comment: But Okay, I posted it on CS SE, you can close this at your ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed the type operator `M`. You can think of it as "giving enough data to capture the effects modeled by the monad."

In general, when thinking about monads as a functional design pattern, you should prefer `bind : ('a -> 'b M) -> 'a M -> 'b M` to `join : 'a M M -> 'a M`. They are mutually derivable, but `bind` plays the more critical role.

To see why, consider an effectful function represented as a function `'a -> 'b M`. Thus, we can consider the Kleisli category to be the category of effectful functions. To spell that out, the Kleisli category has types as objects, and morphisms $A \to B$ are functions `A -> B M`. We can write $\hat{f}$ for the Kleisli morphism $A \to B$ with underlying function `f : A -> B M`. We need an identity and a composition operator. The identity is given by $\eta_A : A \to M A$ or `unit : A -> A M`. Note that in the Kleisli category, this is a morphism $A \to A$, as desired. To compose $\hat{f} : A \to B$ and $\hat{g} : B \to C$, we need to find a way to combine `f : A -> B M` and `g : B -> C M`. We can do this by using `bind` on `g` to get it into the right form: `f; bind(g) : A -> C M` (where `;` is the diagram-order or program-order composition operator). The monad laws are exactly what are needed for this to form a category.